# Prove Paillier cryptosystem decryption $M=L(c^{\lambda(n)}\bmod n^2)\,\mu\bmod n$

Tags: encryption, public-key, homomorphic-encryption, homomorphic-signatures

How can we prove mathematically that in Paillier cryptosystem decryption, our message is equal to the right side of
$$M=L(c^{\lambda(n)}\bmod n^2)\,\mu\bmod n$$

Comment: Lindell's Book has it!

Comment: As kelala mentions, there are plenty of standard sources for this. Perhaps you can show us what you have tried and then we could guide you from there